# Is there a way to check if a connection has been closed then finish the thread?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, networking, rust, tcplistener

With a code similar to that of [this example](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Echo_server#Rust), a connection goes on forever because the infinite loop never stops. I modified it a bit in order to allow reading not to be blocking the thread:

```
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:4444").unwrap();
    println!("Server is running on 127.0.0.1:4444 ...");

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();
        stream
            .set_nonblocking(true)
            .expect("Failed to set stream as nonblocking");
        thread::spawn(move || handle_client(stream));
    }
}

fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut stream = BufReader::new(stream);
    println!("New client logged");

    loop {
        let mut recv_buffer = String::new();
        println!("Before reading");
        let recv_data_size = stream
            .read_line(&mut recv_buffer)
            .expect("Error when reading line");

        if recv_data_size > 0 {
            println!("{}", recv_buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

The client is really simple, connects then send `Hello!` to the server:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:4444").unwrap();
    let _ = stream.write("Hello!".as_bytes());
}
```

When client sends its string and *disconnects*, the server goes into an infinite loop and prints `Before reading` indefinitely. It never knows when to close connection, even though the client ended it long ago.

Is there a way in Rust to check if distant connection has been closed (if possible without having to set a timeout), then finish properly the thread on which it is running?

Comment: When you get a 0 return from read_line() then you know that the client decided to quit.

Comment: The doc is not really precise on this point (given their description that may be wrong to fully rely on this), but since it works now I'll go with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of `read_line`:

> An empty buffer returned indicates that the stream has reached EOF.

So you could do it like this:

```
fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut stream = BufReader::new(stream);
    println!("New client logged");

    loop {
        let mut recv_buffer = String::new();
        println!("Before reading");
        let recv_data_size = stream
            .read_line(&mut recv_buffer)
            .expect("Error when reading line");

        if recv_data_size > 0 {
            println!("{}", recv_buffer);
        } else {
            // stream has reached EOF
            break;
        }
    }
}
```